# unity project to native IOS App integration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

I want to integrate unity project to my native ios Application on a specific screen

I follow below instruction given in below git Repository
https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5

Xcode Version 9.3

unity Version 2018.1.6f1

I got below error
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityTest-gdetosseukppilafpxhvtajaihpk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/UnityTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnityTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
    /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UnityTest-gdetosseukppilafpxhvtajaihpk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/UnityTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnityTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Comment: I think the application might have two entry points (One from Unity and one from the App Delegate. It looks like so because the duplicate symbol is _main). Maybe this will help: http://eppz.eu/blog/override-app-delegate-unity-ios-osx-1/
(If it does not please follow up)